# Get the main parent product categories when a product has multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

Working on my company's Wordpress site which was originally set up by someone else. [Here's a product page](http://topixpharm.com/product/sheer-physical-sunscreen-cream-spf-50/) where you can see what I'm referencing...

The "Skin Condition", "Skin Type", and "Regimen" sections were created for us. I am now trying to replicate the behavior to create the "As Seen In" section. They work via WooCommerce categories - on the product page we have a large list of categories, and we check off those that correspond, and the icons are displayed.

The end result is accomplished in functions.php and style.css. The PHP that was used is as follows:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'skin_condition');

function skin_condition() {

    echo '<div class="skin-icons">';
    echo '<div class="skin-condition-title"><h4>Skin Condition</h4></div>';

    if ( is_product() ){

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ){

            $category_name = $term->name;
            $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail); 

            echo '<div class="skin-condition">';  
            echo '<img class="'.$term->slug.'" title="'.$category_name.'" src="'.$image.'">';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

So this ends up pulling the thumbnails for ALL of the categories applied to the product. Then CSS is used to hide what we don't want in each section:

```css
.skin-condition img.glycolic, .skin-condition img.citrix, .skin-condition img.replenix, 
.skin-condition img.glycolix, .skin-condition img.srs, .skin-condition img.solvere, 
.skin-condition img.resurfix, .skin-condition img.rebrightalyze, .skin-condition img.benzaderm, 
.skin-condition img.acne-regimen, .skin-condition img.cleansetone, .skin-condition img.hydrate, 
.skin-condition img.prevent, .skin-condition img.protect, .skin-condition img.repair, 
.skin-condition img.antioxidants, .skin-condition img.body-care, .skin-condition img.cleansers, 
.skin-condition img.exfoliators, .skin-condition img.eye, .skin-condition img.glycolic, 
.skin-condition img.kits-systems, .skin-condition img.masques-peels, .skin-condition img.masques-peels-specialty, 
.skin-condition img.moisturizers, .skin-condition img.retinols, .skin-condition img.sunscreens, 
.skin-condition img.toners, .skin-condition img.new, .skin-condition img.dry, 
.skin-condition img.normal, .skin-condition img.oily, .skin-condition img.sensitive, 
.skin-condition img.dermatopix, .skin-condition .gly-sal, .skin-condition .elite, 
.skin-condition .peels-specialty, .skin-condition .glycolix-elite, .skin-condition .best-sellers, 
.skin-condition .replenix-acne-solutions, .skin-condition .press-mentions  {
    display: none;
}
```

So I figure there HAS to be a way to do this to avoid that CSS. 
Can I call upon just the one parent category in each section in the PHP? Instead of them all loading up and going "`display: none;`"?

Little visual of the categories if it helps:

[image: Little visual of the categories if it helps.]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE:** To avoid the white screen you have to add **`global $post;`**. Alternatively you could also use **`global $product;`** and **`$product->id`** *(instead of **`$post->ID`**)*.

To get the parent category *(the main category)*, you have to use **`$term->parent`**, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'skin_condition' );
function skin_condition() {

    global $post; // or global $product; and $product->id in get_the_terms() function

    if ( is_product() ){

        echo '<div class="skin-icons">';
        echo '<div class="skin-condition-title"><h4>Skin Condition</h4></div>';

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        // First loop
        foreach ( $terms as $term ){

            // We target the child categories to get the parent ones (based on your screen shot)
            if( $term->parent != 0 ){
                // Storing the parent term objects
                $parent_terms_ids[] = $term->parent;
            }
        }

        // Second loop
        foreach ( $parent_terms_ids as $term_id ){

            // get the object term
            $parent_term = get_term( $term_id, 'product_cat' );

            // Only Main parent terms
            if( $parent_term->parent == 0 ){

                $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                $term_image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);

                echo '<div class="skin-condition">';
                echo '<img class="'.$parent_term->slug.'" title="'.$parent_term->name.'" src="'.$term_image.'">';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful and prompt reply!

I'm trying to implement this now, but unfortunately, my Wordpress is throwing me the white screen of death when I try to clean up all the extraneous whitespace in the file. [This is my complete functions.php](https://codeshare.io/a3y9Mg) after trying to clean it up, but I get WSOD despite no syntax errors that I can see.

Comment: @Olivia I have tested and updated the code… There was just a little thing missing at the beginning: `global $post;`.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I couldn't access the server over the weekend so back at it now. Updated the code and thankfully no white screen, but it's still not quite working. Each section appears but the icons do not, [as you can see here](http://topixpharm.com/product/sheer-physical-sunscreen-cream-spf-50/). [Updated functions.php file here.](https://codeshare.io/a3y9Mg)

Comment: I hope you might be able to take another look :) but in the meantime, I've had to revert to our original functions.php to keep up appearances. If you return, [here](http://imgur.com/a/A88wX) is the result of the most recent functions.php I used in my previous comment, and [here](https://codeshare.io/ayNnQ9) is what the source looked like of it. Thanks.